# Is that possible to "recover" UTC time given local time and geometrical time shift?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I now have server local time and a hour shift to UTC(say +5, -8, etc), how can I recover it to UTC?

Note that it's not as intuitive as it is because of summer time. Currently I am in EDT, which should be UTC+5, but in fact, in summer, we only +4. And unfortunately I don't (want to) know the timezone of the server so I am not sure whether it's possible to calculate the UTC with given info.

My target language is python, but if an solution exists, the language itself shouldn't be a big problem.

Why I have such restriction, is because of [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlist%28v=office.12%29.aspx). It just doesn't return a good text timezone description instead of a number.

following is a real element in practice from my server:

```
<RegionalSettings>
  <Language>1033</Language>
  <Locale>1033</Locale>
  <AdvanceHijri>0</AdvanceHijri>
  <CalendarType>1</CalendarType>
  <Time24>False</Time24>
  <TimeZone>300</TimeZone>
  <SortOrder>2070</SortOrder>
  <Presence>True</Presence>
</RegionalSettings>
```

notice here the timezone field

```
<TimeZone>300</TimeZone>
```

it's in minutes, so it tells me I am somewhere in UTC+5, but not a honest timeshift to UTC.

Comment: Note that in common parlance, one would use the opposite signs that you mentioned.  EST would be UTC-5, and EDT would be UTC-4.  In other words, you might be storing "Minutes West of UTC", but normally you would use "Hours East of UTC".   (Though some APIs, such as JavaScript's `getTimezoneOffset()` do indeed return minutes West.)

Comment: See also "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: @MattJohnson: UTC-4 notation should be avoided: it creates confusion with POSIX-style offsets that have the opposite sign e.g., try to guess what result `dateutil` parser would return (and check). Either a zoneinfo id should be used such as `America/New_York` or if it is clear from context then something like `EDT-0400` or just `-0400` to describe the utc offset. Also, I would understand west, east from GMT but UTC is not a geographical location and it is easier to learn the definition: `local time = utc time + utc offset` -- if you know any of the two values; you can get the third one.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't (want to) know the actual timezone then no, it is not possible in general because some timezones may have the same utc offset now while using different DST rules.

It is possible to generate the list of candidate timezones and utc times from the local time and the "standard" utc offset:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pprint import pprint
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

local_time = datetime(2015, 8, 13, 16, 15)
# standard offset (the current offset may be different)
#NOTE: opposite sign! -- it is not POSIX-style offset
standard_utc_offset_hours = timedelta(hours=-5)

# find all timezones with the same utc offset (in the recent time ~2y)
now = datetime.utcnow()
recent = now.replace(year=now.year - 2)
timezones = defaultdict(set) # recent utc offsets -> timezones
times = set()
for tz in map(pytz.timezone, pytz.all_timezones_set):
    # bisect(_utc_transition_times, input_utc_time) -> index
    # _transition_info[index] -> (offset, dst, tzname)
    # _tzinfos[offset, dst, tzname] -> timezone as pytz tzinfo object
    d = tz.fromutc(now)
    info = d.utcoffset(), d.dst(), d.tzname()
    for i, (offset, dst, tzname) in enumerate(getattr(tz, '_transition_info', [info])):
        if offset == standard_utc_offset_hours:  # same "standard" offset
            times.add(str(tz.localize(local_time, is_dst=None)))
            # group by recent utc offsets
            if not hasattr(tz, '_utc_transition_times'):
                timezones[d.strftime("%z"),].add(tz.zone)
                break
            elif tz._utc_transition_times[i] > recent: # recent rules
                it = (tz.fromutc(t).strftime("%z") for t in tz._utc_transition_times[i:])
                timezones[tuple(set(it))].add(tz.zone)
                break
pprint(times)
pprint(timezones)
```

#### Output

```
{'2015-08-13 16:15:00-03:00',
 '2015-08-13 16:15:00-04:00',
 '2015-08-13 16:15:00-05:00',
 '2015-08-13 16:15:00-06:00'}
{('-0500',): {'America/Eirunepe',
              'America/Porto_Acre',
              'America/Rio_Branco',
              'Brazil/Acre',
              'EST',
              'Etc/GMT+5'},
 ('-0500', '-0400'): {'America/Cayman',
                      'America/Detroit',
                      'America/Fort_Wayne',
                      'America/Grand_Turk',
                      'America/Havana',
                      'America/Indiana/Indianapolis',
                      'America/Indiana/Marengo',
                      'America/Indiana/Petersburg',
                      'America/Indiana/Vevay',
                      'America/Indiana/Vincennes',
                      'America/Indiana/Winamac',
                      'America/Indianapolis',
                      'America/Iqaluit',
                      'America/Kentucky/Louisville',
                      'America/Kentucky/Monticello',
                      'America/Louisville',
                      'America/Montreal',
                      'America/Nassau',
                      'America/New_York',
                      'America/Nipigon',
                      'America/Pangnirtung',
                      'America/Port-au-Prince',
                      'America/Thunder_Bay',
                      'America/Toronto',
                      'Canada/Eastern',
                      'Cuba',
                      'EST5EDT',
                      'US/East-Indiana',
                      'US/Eastern',
                      'US/Michigan'},
 ('-0500', '-0600'): {'America/Bahia_Banderas',
                      'America/Cancun',
                      'America/Chicago',
                      'America/Indiana/Knox',
                      'America/Indiana/Tell_City',
                      'America/Knox_IN',
                      'America/Matamoros',
                      'America/Menominee',
                      'America/Merida',
                      'America/Mexico_City',
                      'America/Monterrey',
                      'America/North_Dakota/Beulah',
                      'America/North_Dakota/Center',
                      'America/North_Dakota/New_Salem',
                      'America/Rainy_River',
                      'America/Rankin_Inlet',
                      'America/Resolute',
                      'America/Winnipeg',
                      'CST6CDT',
                      'Canada/Central',
                      'Chile/EasterIsland',
                      'Mexico/General',
                      'Pacific/Easter',
                      'US/Central',
                      'US/Indiana-Starke'}}
```

Depending on the timezones you choose, four different utc times are possible for the same local time and the "standard" utc offset.

---

It is possible to generate the list of candidate timezones from the local time and the corresponding utc offset (same utc time):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pprint import pprint
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

local_time = datetime(2015, 8, 13, 16, 15)
utc_offset_hours = -4 #NOTE: opposite sign! -- it is not POSIX-style offset

# <local time> = <utc time> + <utc offset>
utc_time = local_time - timedelta(hours=utc_offset_hours)
winter_time = datetime(2015, 1, 1) # northern hemisphere
timezones = defaultdict(list) # winter utc offset -> zones
for tz in map(pytz.timezone, pytz.all_timezones_set):
    tz_time = tz.fromutc(utc_time)
    if tz_time.replace(tzinfo=None) == local_time: # same utc offset now
        # group by winter utc offset
        timezones[tz.fromutc(winter_time).strftime("%Z%z")].append(tz.zone)
pprint(timezones)
```

#### Output

```
{'AMST-0300': ['America/Cuiaba', 'America/Campo_Grande'],
 'AMT-0400': ['Brazil/West',
              'America/Porto_Velho',
              'America/Boa_Vista',
              'America/Manaus'],
 'AST-0400': ['America/Anguilla',
              'America/Antigua',
              'America/Santo_Domingo',
              'America/St_Barthelemy',
              'America/St_Lucia',
              'America/Lower_Princes',
              'America/Blanc-Sablon',
              'America/Martinique',
              'America/Montserrat',
              'America/Grenada',
              'America/Curacao',
              'America/Virgin',
              'America/Kralendijk',
              'America/Puerto_Rico',
              'America/Guadeloupe',
              'America/Dominica',
              'America/Port_of_Spain',
              'America/Aruba',
              'America/Barbados',
              'America/St_Vincent',
              'America/St_Kitts',
              'America/Tortola',
              'America/Marigot',
              'America/St_Thomas'],
 'BOT-0400': ['America/La_Paz'],
 'CST-0500': ['America/Havana', 'Cuba'],
 'EST-0500': ['EST5EDT',
              'America/Fort_Wayne',
              'America/Toronto',
              'America/Kentucky/Monticello',
              'America/Indiana/Vevay',
              'America/Iqaluit',
              'US/East-Indiana',
              'America/Indiana/Vincennes',
              'America/Indiana/Petersburg',
              'US/Eastern',
              'America/Louisville',
              'America/Nassau',
              'America/Indiana/Winamac',
              'Canada/Eastern',
              'America/Nipigon',
              'America/Grand_Turk',
              'America/Port-au-Prince',
              'America/Montreal',
              'America/Thunder_Bay',
              'America/Kentucky/Louisville',
              'America/Detroit',
              'America/New_York',
              'America/Indiana/Indianapolis',
              'America/Pangnirtung',
              'America/Indiana/Marengo',
              'US/Michigan',
              'America/Indianapolis'],
 'GMT+4-0400': ['Etc/GMT+4'],
 'GYT-0400': ['America/Guyana'],
 'PYST-0300': ['America/Asuncion']}
```

As you can see even if some timezones use the same utc offset today they may use different utc offsets at a different date.

You might use some additional info (e.g., country) to disambiguate.

Comment: yak. i can only use north America as additional info(or the US and Canada more specifically). get caught by MS again.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: you could use `tzlocal.get_localzone()` to get the local timezone as pytz tzinfo object. Note: my answer assumes that the input is the *current* utc offset while your question implies that the input is "standard" utc offset. Though it does not change the conclusion that the result is ambiguous and you need additional info.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: I've added solution for "standard" utc offset.

Comment: Be aware that even if you know the country, there are still some edge cases where you cannot disambiguate.  Consider that `2015-11-01T01:00:00-05:00` could be *either* CDT (`America/Chicago`), or EST (`America/New_York`)

Comment: @MattJohnson: that is why I've used *"might"*, to express the uncertainty. Also, look at the results in the answer: there are many many timezones that have the same utc offset at a given (local) time.